# alert when not satisfying the condition should stay on the same pane in a wizard

Tags: javascript

I am trying to check if the user entered particular info or not...if entered on click of the next button on a wizard pane that should be redirected to next pane or else should be on the same pane..

I tried the below code..but when the user doesn't enter info the alert message is popped but it is redirected to next page...what is the mistake i am doing? any help please...

```
checkinginfo: function () {

            if (!this.info) {
                alert("Enter info to proceed!");
                return false;
            }
            else
            return true;
        },
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Without the code calling this function we are unable to help you...

Comment: here it is  var check_info = registry.byId("info_pane");
            check_info.passFunction = dLang.hitch(this, function () {
                this.checkinginfo();
            })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

e.preventDefault() worked for me.

checkinginfo: function (e) {

```
        if (!this.info) {
            alert("Enter info to proceed!");
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        else
        return true;
    },
```